# Team services - Release Management - with on premises machine?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

My requirements are

1. Checkin the code to team services.
2. Perform CI build to deploy the code to DEV machine(on-premises, no internet access).
3. Use release management module on Team services to propagate changes from DEV -> QA -> STG -> Prod.

These actions can be easily performed with TFServer(on-premises) but not sure if it can be done using team services as the deployment machines would not be accessible from outer world.

Please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using VSTS, you could have on-premise Build&Release Agents that require network connectivity to youraccount.visualstudio.com. Note that build and release definitions leverage the same kind of agent (there are no different agents for release or build, it the same multi platform bit of binary code written for .NET Core).

Then the machine the agents run on needs to have network connectivity to the sets of machines you named DEV, QA, STG, Prod, which I will call *target* machines.

I would advise you to create a Build Definition that creates the artifacts (just binaries/xml/config files the build produces). Then create a Release Definition linked to that build: this way it can access to the [artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts)
and deploy them on your *target* machines that have no Internet connectivity. The release definition would contain four environments, the first one has the list of tasks to deploy to DEV, the second to QA and so forth. Each of the environment is triggered by the successful deployment of the previous one, but the DEV which is [automatically started after release creation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-environments#deploymenttriggers).

When your release is created, the execution of your list of tasks starts on one agent running on premise: this is where you could use the combo operation of [copy](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) then [execute PowerShell On Target](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines) operations in order to deploy the artifacts on the target machines.

If, for some environment, the set of tasks is identical or similar, you could create a [Task Group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-tasks#metatasks)
and reuse it in multiple environments.

In summary:

- build agents runs on premise machines;
- build agents needs line of sight to targets machines;
- target machines do not need any Internet connectivity;

The following diagram sums up graphically the line of sight concept between agent and targets:[image: line of sight between targets and agent]